# Do I need to rebuild application after adding a new iPhone in ad hoc distribution?

Tags: iphone, provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm using Ad Hoc distribution to send preview/beta version of my iPhone apps to customers for approval. I'm always sending a zipped application and mobileprovision files.

Sometimes however I encountered situation when nothing in the application changed but we needed to add a new device for testing.

I've added a device in Provisioning portal and assigned it to a provisioning profile my application uses for ad hoc distribution. I've downloaded new mobileprovision file and imported it to xcode now the question is do I need to rebuild the application to enable the app on a new device or would it be enough to just send old build with updated mobileprovision file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, simply installing the new provisioning profile on the target device will do

Comment: N.b., This no longer works with iOS 8 devices.
(http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174939/685)