# Installing provisioning profile on iOS 8.0.2

Tags: ios8, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to install my prov. profile via email,itunes. When I try to tap the prov. profile in email it  just directs me to settings. I believe that there should be a pop up that ask to install the prov. profile but I see none. Did I forget any important parts that cause this trouble or maybe its a bug from new iOS 8 update?

Answer (score 16):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature".  Apple has purposely made it so that they can no longer be installed manually by a user and must be installed by dev tools such as Xcode or device management systems such as MDM.  Additionally, they are no longer shown in Profiles & Device Management and are not removable by the everyday user either.

With iOS 8, Apple has moved to the model that any flow that requires the everyday user to install, remove, or even think about provisioning profiles is flawed and that iOS should handle this automatically on the user's behalf.  If the provisioning profile is expired, iOS should get rid of it automatically.  As apps are deleted, iOS should properly deal with the provisioning aspects automatically.  This philosophy is mentioned in WWDC 2014's talk on Managing Apple Devices around ~42 minutes in.

Comment: I just tried installing an app over the air with Crashlytics and it just worked. Is there something going on with the TestFlight App profile which causes it not to install on iOS 8.0.2?

Comment: Crashlytics is doing it the way Apple is prescribing.  Any one who relies on the user having to install the provisioning profile manually in the Settings apps is affected (such as old TestFlight where they'd give you a provisioning profile directly and have you install it).

Comment: "I am the Apple, you are just hiring the hardware from me. You don't have controll over it, we do because you'r just dumb."

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bug. I'm having the same issue with Testflight.
As a workaround install the profile using Xcode's 'Devices' view.

Comment: The problem is that when you go to the devices window -> right click phone -> view provisioning profile -> click + -> browse for the provisioning profile & choose it -> click install .. nothing happens. I'm not able to install the provisioning profile neither through iTunes (option removed) nor Xcode (a bug or I'm not sure why!)..

Comment: Check the Device Log to see if any useful error message was logged.

Comment: No specific log messages pertaining to the issue. It seems like if you are adding a device to an Xcode managed provisioning profile, Xcode is supposed to handle the addition automatically once you add the UDID in the developer account. However, this was not happening. This post provides a workaround which solved this problem: https://matheusandcode.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/xcode-7-adding-a-new-device-to-an-xcode-managed-provisioning-profile/