# Install a provisioning profile on iOS 8 device through iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, provisioning-profile, ipod-touch, ios8.1

I have problems installing an iOS `provisioning profile` on my device. I created a new `development provisioning profile` and added the UDID of my device, dragged it into iTunes and hitted sync but it's not installed on my device.
I also tried to send it as an attachment through email but after tapping the attached profile it only opens the `Profiles` section on the device. 
I'm using an iPod Touch 5G with iOS 8.1.
How to get the provisioning profile installed?

Answer (score 2):

Install the profile into Xcode and your app.  Make sure your profile is selected in the build settings for your app.  Connect your device through USB tethering, and build and run your app on your device.  There is no need to explicitly install the profile onto your machine unless there is an app there that will use it.

Comment: I think what the OP wants to do is update the provisioning profile without having to rebuild the ipa file, and then install on a novel device (which you used to be able to do under iOS 7 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86A7wcJxOqM).

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has been intentionally removed from iOS 8 by apple.
More discussion can be found [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26174939/685).